# My get variables are not working locally?

Tags: macos

I dont get the get variables but when i put the code in production the get variables display....is there something that i need to turn on on my mac to make this work

I am pretty sure i have mod rewrite on....any ideas

also this is in my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your `httpd.conf` file looking for something like this:

```
<Directory "{your_htdocs_dir}">
    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...
</Directory>
```

According to: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html:

*The use of .htaccess files can be disabled completely by setting the AllowOverride directive to "none"*.

Change it to: `AllowOverride All` (or something more secure, you can find options in the mentioned link) and it should work.